# How to create and run a new thread?

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading, c++-cli, managed-c++

I've created a `System::Windows::Forms` class that defines function:

```
System::Void expanding(System::Windows::Forms::TreeViewEventArgs^ e)
{
    //some code
}
```

Which I want to invoke in separated thread by typing:

```
Thread^ thisThread = gcnew Thread(
    gcnew ThreadStart(this,&Form1::expanding(e)));
    thisThread->Start();
```

where `e` is passed by `afterCheck` function from the `treeView` component.

According to [this example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts553s52%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) everything should work fine but instead I get a compiler error:

> error C3350: 'System::Threading::ThreadStart' : a delegate constructor expects 2 argument(s)

and

> error C2102: '&' requires l-value

I tried to create a new instance of `Form1` exactly as it was showed in the MSDN example, but my results are the same.

---

What @Tudor adivced did the trick. But using **System::Threading** i couldn't modify any components from Form1 class.
So i was looking for some other solution and i've found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

And maybe i didn't understand the way **BackgroundWorker** works but it blocks GUI.

What i wanted to acomplish was to run separate thread (whatever way it needs to be done) that will leave gui managable, so the user will be able to stop process with particular button and this new thread would be able to use components from parent thread.

here is my sample code using **BackgroundWorker**

```
//Worker initialization
this->backgroundWorker1->WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            this->backgroundWorker1->DoWork += gcnew System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventHandler(this, &Form1::backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            this->backgroundWorker1->ProgressChanged += gcnew System::ComponentModel::ProgressChangedEventHandler(this, &Form1::backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
            this->backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerCompleted += gcnew System::ComponentModel::RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this, &Form1::backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
```

Asynchronous operation is invoked by Button click event handler

```
System::Void fetchClick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         dirsCreator();//List of directories to be fetched
         backgroundWorker1 ->RunWorkerAsync();       
     }
```

**DoWork** function is a basic recursive fetching function

```
System::Void fetch(String^ thisFile)
     {
         try{
         DirectoryInfo^ dirs = gcnew DirectoryInfo(thisFile);
         array<FileSystemInfo^>^dir = (dirs->GetFileSystemInfos());
         if(dir->Length>0)

             for(int i =0 ;i<dir->Length;i++)
             {
                 if((dir[i]->Attributes & FileAttributes::Directory) == FileAttributes::Directory)
                     fetch(dir[i]->FullName);
                 else
                     **backgroundWorker1 -> ReportProgress(0, dir[i]->FullName);**//here i send results to be printed on gui RichTextBox

             }
         }catch(...){}
      }
```

And here is reporting function

```
System::Void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::ProgressChangedEventArgs^  e) {
             this->outputBox->AppendText((e->UserState->ToString())+"\n");
             this->progressBar1->Value = (this->rand->Next(1, 99));
         }
```

Comment: As a note, Visual C++ is simply the IDE. C++/CLI is the name for the extensions to C++ that Microsoft added to support managed integration.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to specify the parameter to the function call:

```
Thread^ thisThread = gcnew Thread(
         gcnew ThreadStart(this,&Form1::expanding));
         thisThread->Start();
```

Also the function should not take any parameters, otherwise it does not conform to the `ThreadStart` signature.

Have a look at the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx#Y0) of `Thread` for some more examples.

Comment: +1, in the OP's example he was trying to take the address of the return value of a method call.

Comment: `Form1::expanding` is correct in C++/CLI for an instance method. The first parameter to the delegate constructor, `this`, specifies which object to call the method on.

Comment: @David Yaw: Right, sorry, don't know what I was thinking. :)